# Safely deserialize only what I need

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I was wondering if my method for deserialization would cause any problems. I have been reading JSON responses from an API into classes for future reference like so:

```
var response = await client.DeleteAsync(resource);

return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<FolderResult>();
```

And FolderResult is a class.

```
class FolderResult
{
    public string FolderId { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

}

My issue is, sometimes the API returns a different set of JSON values, e.g. the JSON returns message, path, size, and weight, but I still cast the response to FolderResult. When I call message (my only desired value) from the resulting FolderResult, the value is correct.

My question is, would I ever run into problems doing this? Or can I safely parse only what I need and ignore the extra response values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem as long as your `message` property will remain. Although if you only need the `message` string, you can retrieve it using [`JObject.SelectToken`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SelectToken.htm)

```
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var jObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var message = (string)jObject.SelectToken("message");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine leaving the class as is. It will work. When the returned json does not have message in it, the message string in your FolderResult is set to null. All the other json data that is in the payload returned by api is ignored.